# Search counts vary by screen

Tags: search, 4.7.6

I have set up a smart group to list current memberships by chapter. When I search contacts by a certain chapter I get 222 contacts. If I search by the smart group defined for that chapter I get 221 contacts. If I search memberships by that chapter I again get 222 contacts. I hit the update counts link in the groups page but the smart group count stays at 221.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching by **Memberships** then it is possible that a contact will have more than one membership, eg if one Expired and a new Membership record has been created for them.

If you are comparing that with a search of **Contacts**, then the numbers will differ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the smart group as a mailing list to send out a bulk email through CiviMail?

If so, then someone may have unsubscribed from the group through the link in the email.

Comment: Good point - or an Admin may have 'removed' them - want to add that you should be able to look at the contacts in the Group and look in the Find Contacts within this Group and filter to 'removed'?